# Folder Upload with Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core

I understand that file upload is possible with Angular Js. But I researched and found no provisions for an entire folder to be uploaded.
I am working on ASP.NET Core.

Is folder uploading possible with AngularJS. Alternatives are welcome as well.
Also I am wondering what is the equivalent of FolderBrowserDialog in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modern browsers support the [File and Directory Entries API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) which allows handling of directories (folders). At the time of writing, this [works in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Safari TP](https://caniuse.com/#search=webkitdire) (no old IE support).

You have at least two ways to implement this (brownie points for doing both for best UX!).

## Method 1: Using file input

Give the standard `input` element the power to handle directories via the [`webkitdirectory`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) attribute:

```
<input
    #folderInput
    type="file"
    (change)="filesPicked(folderInput.files)"
    webkitDirectory
>
```

*Note: the above HTML snippet assumes Angular 2+, but you can easily do the same thing in Angular 1*

`folderInput.files` will be a flat list of all files within the folder, no need to recursively walk the tree or anything like that. Just iterate through the files in a simple loop like this:

```
function filesPicked(files) {
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        const path = file.webkitRelativePath.split('/');
        // upload file using path
        ...
    }
}
```

The property [`webkitRelativePath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/webkitRelativePath), as the name suggests, contains a path of the file relative to the ancestor directory the user selected.

## Method 2: Using drag and drop

Another part of the same File and Directory Entries API is [`DataTransferItem.webkitGetAsEntry()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry) which returns a `FileSystemFileEntry` or `FileSystemDirectoryEntry`. If it's a directlry, you can read it via a `FileSystemDirectoryReader` retrieved by calling `FileSystemDirectoryEntry.createReader()`. Here's a brief example of handling the drop event:

```
function drop(event) {
    const items = event.dataTransfer.items;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        const item = items[i];
        if (item.kind === 'file') {
            const entry = item.webkitGetAsEntry();
            if (entry.isFile) {
                 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    entry.file( 
                        file => {
                            resolve(file);
                        },
                        err => {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                    );
                });
            } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
                const directoryReader = entry.createReader();
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    directoryReader.readEntries(
                        entries => {
                            resolve(entries);
                        },
                        err => {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                    );
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My coworker wrote [a short article](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2018/01/03/folder-upload-in-an-angular-app/) explaining the approach in more detail (disclaimer: I work for that company).

Here's a fully working Plunkr demo from the article: https://plnkr.co/edit/rFC9Ln

Answer (score 0):

ng-file-upload is a well known AngularJS file upload module.

It talks about multiple file uploads. Not sure if its exactly what you want.

Heres the link ...

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/master/README.md#user-content--usage

Answer (score -1):

[Flow.js](https://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/) allows you to upload folders of images. I haven't tried it with other file types though.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out :)

Answer (score -1):

Uploading folder is not possible. You may upload single file, multiple files or zip files.

For this you may use `ng-file-upload`

[You may get this module over here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Comment: if I had a dollar for every time told me something wasn't possible lol